# Set page number in cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to get multiple pagination on same template. I am querying 2 different models to paginate in 2 different places of a template file file. As you have guessed if I click next page of one of both pagination, both the models fetches next page values.
 I have done enough research and tried various solutions available online but none of them worked. May be i dint used them correctly.

I have figured out that if I can be able to set page no statically i can get it worked.

I want to set it like

> 'page'=>1

I know we can set it like that. But if there is a param in url like

> ...../page:2/....

It is overriding the value i specified. Is there a way to get pages of numbers we gave no matter what is sent through URL?

Thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**2 Suggestion**

First, you can overwrite the page number in the URL parameters, like this

```
$this->request->params['named']['page'] = YOUR_FAVORITE_INTEGER;
```

The problem with this is that the URL on the page will still have the old `:page` value set, so...

The other approach is to redirect to the same controller action, but with a different page number set (or no page number set, if you like).

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'whatever', 'page' => YOUR_FAVORITE_INTEGER));
```

Here are the docs on constructing redirects, in case you need them:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerurl

Answer (score 1):

Even better and simpler, I used this and worked in Cake 1.3. Not sure if it will work on 2.x

In the controller:

```
$this->paginator['page']= YOUR_FAVORITE_INTEGER;
```

No detected problems, so far.

Comment: Just had to do this for 2.x its now: $this->Paginator->settings['page'] = YOUR_FAVORITE_INTEGER;

Answer (score 1):

Try to add :

```
$this->Paginator->settings['Model1']['page']=YourFavInteger;
$this->Paginator->settings['Model2']['page']=YourFavInteger;

$this->Paginator->paginate('Model1');
$this->Paginator->paginate('Model2');
```

to your controller.